# How to fix - ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert (x, y) with type tuple)?

Tags: python, pandas, traceback, pyarrow, streamlit

I'm trying to build a streamlit app. Below is the working example I'm trying

```
from pm4py.objects.conversion.log import converter as log_converter
import pandas as pd
import pm4py
df = pm4py.format_dataframe(pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pm4py/pm4py-core/release/notebooks/data/running_example.csv', sep=';'), case_id='case_id',activity_key='activity',
                             timestamp_key='timestamp')

log = log_converter.apply(df)
```

```
precedence_dict = pm4py.discover_dfg(log)[0]
```

**precedence_dict** is a dict of (antecedent,consequent) and count

```
precedence_dict  = {('check ticket', 'decide'): 6,
         ('check ticket', 'examine casually'): 2,
         ('check ticket', 'examine thoroughly'): 1,
         ('decide', 'pay compensation'): 3,
         ('decide', 'reinitiate request'): 3,
         ('decide', 'reject request'): 3,
         ('examine casually', 'check ticket'): 4,
         ('examine casually', 'decide'): 2,
         ('examine thoroughly', 'check ticket'): 2,
         ('examine thoroughly', 'decide'): 1,
         ('register request', 'check ticket'): 2,
         ('register request', 'examine casually'): 3,
         ('register request', 'examine thoroughly'): 1,
         ('reinitiate request', 'check ticket'): 1,
         ('reinitiate request', 'examine casually'): 1,
         ('reinitiate request', 'examine thoroughly'): 1
}
```

Converting the above `dict` to pandas dataframe

```
precedence_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(precedence_dict, orient='index').reset_index()


rename_map = {"index" : "Antecedent,Consequent", 0 : "Count"}
precedence_df = precedence_df.rename(columns=rename_map)
```

```
precedence_df['Antecedent'], precedence_df['Consequent'] = zip(*precedence_df["Antecedent,Consequent"])
# precedence_df.assign(**dict(zip(['Antecedent', 'Consequent'], precedence_df["Antecedent,Consequent"].str)))
# precedence_df['Antecedent'], precedence_df['Consequent'] = precedence_df["Antecedent,Consequent"].str
precedence_mat = precedence_df[['Antecedent', 'Consequent', 'Count']]
```

```
st.dataframe(precedence_df)
```

I got the ArrowInvalid Error while running the app at this line

Complete error traceback

```
ArrowInvalid: ("Could not convert (x, y) with type tuple: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type", 'Conversion failed for column Antecedent, Consequent with type object')

Traceback:
File "C:\Users\zz\Documents\Streamlit\preced\app.py", line 1353, in <module>
    st.dataframe(precedence_df)
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\dataframe_selector.py", line 85, in dataframe
    return self.dg._arrow_dataframe(data, width, height)
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\arrow.py", line 82, in _arrow_dataframe
    marshall(proto, data, default_uuid)
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\arrow.py", line 160, in marshall
    proto.data = type_util.data_frame_to_bytes(df)
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\type_util.py", line 371, in data_frame_to_bytes
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
File "pyarrow\table.pxi", line 1561, in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_pandas
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 595, in dataframe_to_arrays
    for c, f in zip(columns_to_convert, convert_fields)]
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 595, in <listcomp>
    for c, f in zip(columns_to_convert, convert_fields)]
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 581, in convert_column
    raise e
File "c:\users\zz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 575, in convert_column
    result = pa.array(col, type=type_, from_pandas=True, safe=safe)
File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 302, in pyarrow.lib.array
File "pyarrow\array.pxi", line 83, in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array
File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 99, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
```

Current pyarrow version 5.0.0.

I DON'T HAVE ANY ISSUES/ERRORS when I tried to run the same code in colab(expect st.dataframe), I don't have any issues/errors. What does ArrowInavlid Error mean, how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with streamlit and `st.dataframe` but it looks like it's trying to convert `precedence_df` to a `pyarrow.Table`.

While in `pandas` you can have arbitrary objects as the data type of your column, in `pyarrow` it's not possible. So the column `Antecedent,Consequent` is causing issues because it's a tuple.

```
|    | Antecedent,Consequent                        |   Count |
|---:|:---------------------------------------------|--------:|
|  0 | ('check ticket', 'decide')                   |       6 |
|  1 | ('check ticket', 'examine casually')         |       2 |
|  2 | ('check ticket', 'examine thoroughly')       |       1 |
|  3 | ('decide', 'pay compensation')               |       3 |
|  4 | ('decide', 'reinitiate request')             |       3 |
|  5 | ('decide', 'reject request')                 |       3 |
```

It's easier and more idiomatic to work on a dataframe like `precedence_mat`, because it uses flat strings columns (instead of tuples).

```
|    | Antecedent         | Consequent         |   Count |
|---:|:-------------------|:-------------------|--------:|
|  0 | check ticket       | decide             |       6 |
|  1 | check ticket       | examine casually   |       2 |
|  2 | check ticket       | examine thoroughly |       1 |
|  3 | decide             | pay compensation   |       3 |
|  4 | decide             | reinitiate request |       3 |
```

Having that said you have two options if you really need to pass tuples to pyarrow/streamlit:

1. Create a schema for your tuples and use it to convert the dataframe to pyarrow before passing it to streamlit.

It's a bit tricky, you need to provide a schema for your tuples, explaining what they are:

```
import pyarrow as pa


schema  = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field(
            "Antecedent,Consequent",
            pa.struct(
                [
                    pa.field("antecedent", pa.string()),
                    pa.field("consequent", pa.string()),
                ])
        ),
        pa.field("Count", pa.int32())
    ]

)

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(precedence_df, schema=schema)
st.dataframe(table)
```

2. Convert the tuples to list,
   which makes it easier for pyarrow to guess the type

```
copy_df = precedence_df.copy()
copy_df["Antecedent,Consequent"] = precedence_df["Antecedent,Consequent"].apply(list)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(copy_df).to_pandas()
st.dataframe(table)
```

Note that in this case the "Antecedent,Consequent" data is converted from tuple of strings to list of strings.

Comment: This is working. Thank You. But the solution was not working in colab.

Comment: Also the desired output is a flat strings column. Used  `table1 = pd.DataFrame(table["Antecedent,Consequent"].to_list(), columns=['Antecedent','Consequent'])` to split list of strings to separate columns